# Selected folder doesn't contain a config.xml in phonegap

Tags: hybrid-mobile-app, phonegap-desktop-app

[image]I am using windows 7 .my antivirus is now disabled. I want to build a hybrid app. i downloaded phone gap. when i creating new phone gap project their shows "Selected folder doesn't contain a config.xml ". I tried lot of time but i cant able to create a project .after seeing this message selected folder contain 4 folders but it is empty. I want to built a hybrid app but i am stuck in beginning stage.so please help me to solve problem.
i am attaching screenshot of project creation and error message .1st screen shot is how i created project.2nd one is error message when i click create project.3rd one is empty folders created in selected folder for creating project.

[image]
[image]

When i select a folder with config file it show below error...[image]

Comment: This question is not specific at all. Please provide more detail and list your specific issue. Stack Overflow doesn't write code for you so please list your specific issue.

Comment: Charlie Fish, now i added all screenshots of problem .now can u help me to solve the problem

Comment: Have you tried looking in "app/platforms/ios/AppName/config.xml"?

Comment: i added a new image when i tries to select a folder which already have config.xml file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helped me to create the project through the PhoneGap CLI and then just add the project in the Gui. That worked for me

1. Install phonegap Cli with npm: npm install -g phonegap@latest
2. Go to your project folder and create the project: phonegap create testproject
3. Start the PhoneGap Desktop App and add the existing project

Comment: answer is not clear and complete please say in detail

Answer (score 0):

We've pinpointed the issue, there seems to be have been a recent change to the template and it seems to have a compatibility issue with the connect-phonegap create API which is used by PhoneGap Desktop to create projects.

We're currently working on a fix.

In the mean time you can also use the PhoneGap CLI as an alternative.

Comment: We've made a fix to the template, however you'll need to reset your template cache by deleting the `.cordova` folder.

On Mac:

`/Users/<username>/.cordova`

On Windows:

`C:\Users\<username>\.cordova`

Comment: hello i have install phonegap desktop app ver 0.3.3 on windows 10 and its install but its not showing server is running? is that error or bug?

Comment: @AnujKhandelwal try downloading Desktop Version 0.3.5 and let me know if the issue is still occurring for you.

Comment: thanks but its also not work, still server not running and not showing any error.. is there any installation process or something else that i missed..as i have tried to run administration mode and windows 7 compatibility mode also but still no luck

Comment: I have try 0.1.8 on windows 10 also and its showing server is offline.

Comment: Are you using a firewall or AV softeware? Are you using a corporate network or home network?

Comment: i'm using home network and i have change permission in windows firewall and using microsoft security essential that came by default with windows 10